# Yii2 and Postman - empty POST

Tags: yii2, postman

Again yii2, again problem.
I need yii/rest/Controller, not yii/rest/ActiveController
I have contorller with method and config:
[my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aYFf.jpg)

my Postman:
[my postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbrcE.jpg)

Always have empty POST array. Where is problem? If send as form-data, all is well.

Comment: I suppose the JSON format of your request body is not valid. Could you try sending data through the x-www-urlencoded option?

Comment: Thanks, x-www-urlencoded and form-data work well, but i need json. He is 100% valid, and worked on another project with Yii2. But I do not have it already

Comment: Can be a problem in nginx?

Comment: I don't think it's due to nginx, but rather Yii2's controller might be unable to parse the JSON string it receives probably.

Comment: Can you try and send this string-> {"article": "12012", "brand_id": "60"}

Comment: verify the contents of `Yii::$app->request->bodyParams` also if you are using debug extension, check weather the request section shows any more relevant info

Comment: Try to dump the result of `Yii::$app->request->getRawBody()`

Comment: i try  {"article": "12012", "brand_id": "60"} - the same result              Yii::$app->request->bodyParams  - the same result

Comment: Yii::$app->request->getRawBody() - show me string(46) "{
  "article": "1111111",
 "brand_id": "60"
}  
"  This is already something. But why not data in POST?

Comment: @Billizzard seems that you missed header: `content-type: application/json` in headers section of postman

Comment: I have checked checkbox in Header (in postman): Content-type: application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found! I Found!! I FOUND ANSWER!!!!
Thank you to all the good people who helped me find the answer. 
And i'm sorry. Answer is very simple) Just use 
**Yii::$app->request->post()**
I forgot about it)) Uhhh .....